# JavaScript/HTML5 based solution for a t-shirt design tool

Tags: javascript, software-development, html, clothing

I'm looking for a JavaScript/HTML5 based solution for a t-shirt design tool, similar to this one: https://www.customink.com/lab. I'm looking for preferably an open source with following features:

- adding custom text elements
- adding custom raster images
- changing font properties (family, size) for text
- manipulating elements: moving, scaling and rotating
- removing elements
- masking/limiting editing area

Must be modifiable (so can't be closed source or SaaS). I also don't want to use Flash-based solutions. So far I have only found this (which is based on fabric.js): https://github.com/imomin/CustomTShirt but am wondering what are other alternatives. Will be grateful for any suggestions.