# Automatic generation of images from mockup

Tags: image-processing

I'm currently making a website that's an ecommerce, and I sell T-Shirts, hundreds of them. I have some images that serves as 'mockups' for my products, that is a person wearing a flat T-Shirt. I'm looking for a way to generate all those images. Currently, the only way I know of doing this is to use Photoshop, and applying the masks correctly, but I hope there's a smarter way of doing so. Does anyone know?

- Any OS
- Free or Paid

Comment: Did you look at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11383/web-based-garment-builder and http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/javascript-html5-based-solution-for-a-t-shirt-design-tool  Maybe not perfect for you, but some of the answer & complements might help

Comment: Yes I did, thank you, but it does not solve my issue. Photoshop Actions are a dumb way to do it, as seen here: http://lifehacker.com/5776749/how-to-automate-anything-in-photoshop?disableinsets=off&utm_expid=66866090-49.VYy4WCNHSyuP6EmjnM93MQ.1

Comment: Can you code JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

- is a command line tool, ideal for doing batch processing
- provides [composite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php) that allows you to combine two images
- is free
- for many OS

[image: Smiley] over [image: Flower] gives [image: Combined]

If I understood the request correctly, you take the Flat T-Shirt as the background and add the logo or slogan on top of it.

It has all kind of [geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#geometry) options to place the picture at the correct location.